# Multiplying signed to unsigned binary numbers in verilog

Tags: digital-logic, filter, verilog, binary

How can I multiply a signed number to unsigned number in verilog for example:

a = 6'b111111 ; //which is means -1 as it is signed

b = 6'b111111 ; //which is means 63 as it is unsigned

I want the result be -63 which is 1000001 which is signed number

Comment: do you mean adding, or multiplying, there's a big difference? Please alter your title, or your question text.

Answer (score 6):

The width of your expression is very important when dealing with signed arithmetic. To multiply two 6-bit numbers and get a result of -63, you need at least 7 bits. You also need `a` to be sign extended to 7 bits. However, in Verilog, whenever you mix signed and unsigned operands, you get an unsigned result. So you need to convert `b` to at least a 7-bit signed value. You can do that as shown below:

```
module top;
   bit signed [5:0] a = -1;
   bit [5:0]        b = 63;
   bit signed [6:0] c;

   initial begin
      c = a*$signed({1'b0,b});
      $display("%b %d",c,c);
   end
endmodule
```